# SQLSRV Update Query to remove spaces

Tags: php, sql-server

Using a combination of MS-SQL, PHP, and JSON, I have a column in my page called VendorAddress that outputs to the browser like this:

```
 1111 THAT WAY DRIVE �TORRANCE
```

That strange black diamond with the questionmark.

I have narrowed it down to the fact that some users are copying and pasting from Excel, and there is an extra space between the street and city.  I can prevent this from happening in the future.  It's the ones that already been saved to the table that is causing a problem for me.

I have found there are over 300 records in the MS-SQL database that have this extra space.

What I need to do is write a query that would update the column by removing this extra space.

```
 UPDATE [main].[dbo].[suppliers] SET [VendorAddress] = '1111 THAT WAY DRIVE TORRANCE' WHERE [PartnerCode] = '00011144';
```

This is the query I was using, going record for record for each PartnerCode that has the black diamond (336 total).  I refuse to go record for record on this.  I need to write a query that will do it for me.

I am not sure how to go about doing this.  Everything I find online tells me to use TRIM, but it's only for trailing spaces.  These are not trailing spaces.  They are within the string.

I wish to write a query that would look at the whole table and remove the unnecessary spaces from within the string.

### Edit

The special character cannot be seen in the database itself.  The only time you see it is when PHP outputs it to the browser.

Basically, within the table, the field contains an extra space.  The black diamond cannot be seen within the table.

Comment: Are there `336` records in your table, or only `336` records with the incorrect character? If you know the incorrect character you should be able to use `replace`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Comment: why not `update .. set vendoraddress=replace(vendoraddress, '�', '')`. no need to do individual records. just nuke the character from orbit in ALL records.

Comment: @MarcB - I just edited my question.  The black diamond is not visible in the table itself.

Comment: well, figure out what character it is (e.g the raw bytes) and then use those in your replace.

Comment: @MarcB - from what I could find, it's not a character at all.  It's merely an extra space in the string.

Comment: @HoodCoderMan Output the actual characters in a record you now has it and you should see it (not visually looking at the characters in a browser).

Comment: @HoodCoderMan : The black diamond is a placeholder for a missing unicode glyph, it's most definitely not an extra space.  Different applications will render if different glyphs to represent unknown characters and down will render nothing at all.  In FireFox it's rendered as a box with the UTF-16 Hex Code value.

Comment: @MyItchyChin - How can I remove it?  I attempted your code below by first trying to select all the records that have this character, but I cannot seem to return the 336 records that have it.

Comment: @HoodCoderMan - I've updated my answer with some code to help you capture the glyph into a char variable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should be able to just employe the REPLACE function:

```
UPDATE [main].[dbo].[suppliers] 
    SET [VendorAddress] = REPLACE(VendorAddress, '�', '')
```

This command seems to work:

```
SELECT REPLACE('1111 THAT WAY DRIVE �TORRANCE', '�', '')
```

Comment: Apologies - I just updated my question.  The black diamond is not visible within the table.

Comment: For me, it looks like it may show up as a "?".  This might still work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating it away? Here's some code for capturing the glyph if copy/paste won't work.

```
DECLARE @Glyph CHAR(1);

SELECT @Glyph = SUBSTRING([VendorAddress]
                          , -- Put numberic position of Glyph in string here
                          ,1)
FROM [main].[dbo].[suppliers]
WHERE [PartnerCode] = '00011144';  -- Record with erroneous Glyph

SELECT @Glyph AS [Questionable Character]
     , [VendorAddress] AS [Before]
     , REPLACE([VendorAddress],@Glyph,'') AS [After]
WHERE [PartnerCode] = '00011144';  -- Use same record as above.    

/*  Uncomment out this bit when you know it works...
UPDATE [main].[dbo].[suppliers] 
SET [VendorAddress] = REPLACE([VendorAddress],@Glyph,'')
WHERE [VendorAddress] LIKE '%' + @Glyph + '%';
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

To replace double spaces with a single space use the following:

```
UPDATE [main].[dbo].[suppliers]
 SET [VendorAddress] = replace([VendorAddress], '  ',' ')
 WHERE [VendorAddress] LIKE '%  %'
```

Repeat it until you get 0 rows affected.

*** EDIT ***

Otherwise can you execute this query to find out the code of that character?

```
select distinct cast([VendorAddress] AS varbinary) FROM [main].[dbo].[suppliers] WHERE [VendorAddress] LIKE '1111 THAT WAY DRIVE%TORRANCE'
```

Comment: It isn't double spaces, it is a specific incorrect character.

Comment: Attempted to use the select above, but it returned no records.

Comment: Does the following works?
_select cast([VendorAddress] AS varbinary) FROM [main].[dbo].[suppliers] WHERE [PartnerCode] = '00011144'_

Comparing the result with this:
_select cast('1111 THAT WAY DRIVE TORRANCE' AS varbinary)_
we could get the hex code of that unwanted character.
Or not?

Comment: Using select cast([VendorAddress] AS varbinary) FROM [main].[dbo].[suppliers] WHERE [PartnerCode] = '00011144' brings this result back:  0x504F20424F582039343132363520A04D49414D49

Comment: The one extracted by the query is another address: _"PO BOX 941265  MIAMI"_
Try with this: _select distinct [VendorAddress], cast([VendorAddress] AS varbinary) FROM [main].[dbo].[suppliers]_ and find the binary string linked to the address in question.